# Allow HTML in OpenCart Information Page

Tags: php, opencart

I want to allow HTML code to be placed on the Information page of an Opencart site. Right now it appears as if the HTML is being run through htmlspecialchars(), which I want to be the case for comments and such, but not for the information page.

Answer (score 1):

You can put html in as long as you change to the `source` on the WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Yes, I believe PHP is supported to? I place jQuery, HTML and CSS inside that.

Comment: While it's possible to add PHP code, it won't execute (unless you modify the controller code to do so)